# What does "Some Principal APIs could not be loaded" during TomEE 8.0.x container startup signal?

Tags: jwt, apache-tomee, tomee-7, tomee-8

While migrating several projects from a TomEE-7.x environment to the new TomEE-8.0.x container (8.0.0-M2), I'm finding this message in the logs during startup of the container

```
INFO - Some Principal APIs could not be loaded: 
     org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken out of 
     org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken not found.
```

This message is printed to the console independent of

- what web project I deploy in TomEE-8, and
- which [TomEE variant](http://tomee.apache.org/download-ng.html) I choose, that is `microprofile`, `webprofile` or `plus`.

### My questions

- What does it signal to me? Do I have to take care for something?
- Are any actions required from my side to compensate this message? Which ones?

Any solid advice welcome.

Comment: I can confirm via the official example pages: https://tomee.apache.org/latest/examples/applicationcomposer-jaxws-cdi.html